# Error while compiling ncurses app on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, compilation, ncurses, curses

I'm trying to compile ncurses based app on Mac OS X 10.6.8 but I get this error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_initscr", referenced from:
      _main in ccf8K8YG.o
  "_printw", referenced from:
      _main in ccf8K8YG.o
  "_stdscr", referenced from:
      _main in ccf8K8YG.o
  "_wrefresh", referenced from:
      _main in ccf8K8YG.o
  "_wgetch", referenced from:
      _main in ccf8K8YG.o
  "_endwin", referenced from:
      _main in ccf8K8YG.o
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Are the libraries you are trying to link against in x86_64 format? Can you try to build your application in x86 format and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: What linker options are you using? Have you got the app to run on another platform (eg linux) or has it never compiled? You'll need some argument `-lncurses` in the final stage when you generate your executable (or else load the ncurses functions dynamically).

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure this is because you're not including the `ncurses` library when compiling.

Try adding:

```
-lncurses
```

when compiling.

For example (for C++):

```
g++ -o hello main.cpp -lncurses
```

Or using gcc (for C):

```
gcc -o hello main.cpp -lncurses
```

This short command will compile and execute:

```
gcc -o hello main.cpp -lncurses && ./hello
```

This was my issue, I hope this helps someone.